# How to pass middleware as param to module

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-storage, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to fit a piece of code block in my existing code but unable to understand how to pass the middleware in the coding pattern I am using.

The piece of code I want to integrate in my code patter:

```
router.post(
    '/appuser/uploadavatar',
    multer.single('image'),
    gcsMiddlewares.sendUploadToGCS,
    (req, res, next) => {
        if (req.file && req.file.gcsUrl) {
            return res.status(200).send({'avatar': req.file.gcsUrl});
        }
        return res.status(500).send('Unable to upload');
    },
);
```

What I have:

```
app.js:

var v1 = require('./routes/v1');
app.use('/api/v1', v1);
```

then route/v1.js having:

```
// routes/vi.js:

const auth = require('../controllers/authenticateUsers');

router.post('/:entity/:action', handlePOSTs);



function handlePOSTs(req, res) {
   switch(req.params.entity) {
     case "auth":
       switch(req.params.action) {
         case "uploadavatar":
                    auth.uploadAvatar(req, res);
                    break;
       }
     break;
   }
}
```

in auth.uploadAvatar:

```
// authenticateUsers.js


exports.uploadAvatar = (req, res, next) => {
    // here is where I want to execute this pattern :
    // router.post(
    //     '/appuser/uploadavatar',
    //     multer.single('image'),
    //     gcsMiddlewares.sendUploadToGCS,
    //     (req, res, next) => {
    //         if (req.file && req.file.gcsUrl) {
    //             return res.status(200).send({'avatar': req.file.gcsUrl});
    //         }
    //         return res.status(500).send('Unable to upload');
    //     },
    // );
}
```

How to pass middleware to an exported function?

Comment: This seems like you are creating a single route to handle all actions in your api with this. If this limitation is not set in stone, then I highly recommend you create separate, more restful routes that clearly define a single responsibility.

Comment: @Chev thank you for the help, I have refactored everything to separate out routes mapped to specific functions and it is working now.

Comment: Great stuff. Good luck with the project.